# Recovering from human error with a delayed member?

Tags: mongodb

According to [MongoDB Docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replication/#delayed-members)

> Delayed members may help recover from various kinds of human error. Such errors may include inadvertently deleted databases or botched application upgrades.

How do I recover from such errors?

I assume that I:

1. Stop the delayed member.
2. `mongo dump --oplog`
3. `mongorestore --oplogReplay`

How do I tell mongorestore to replay everything except the offending operation?

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: check this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog/15451297#15451297

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the detailed answer to the following question:  [Modify and replay MongoDB oplog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog/15451297#15451297) it is exactly the same as the answer to your question would be.

Comment: That answer describes recovering from a backup and the oplog.  I am interested in knowing the steps to recover from a delayed member.  And replaying the oplog with the offending op filtered out.  I'd like to replay the ops after the offending op as well as the ops before it.

Comment: That's not supported.  You can do it by turning the "undesired" operation into a no-op but you would be doing that at your own risk.  Technically all the operations after the "bad" one are suspect - given that valid data is missing or invalid data is present do you really want to accept writes that come in at that point?

Comment: In any case, the way you use delayed secondary _is_ by making a backup off of it that you can restore into your "affected" nodes.