# Taking EBS snapshot for multiple mongo node EBS volumes in mongoDB cluster

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, snapshot

I have journal and data both on the same volume for a mongoDB shard, so the consistency problem of taking snapshots only after locking using fsyncLock is not needed. An EBS snapshot would be consistent point in time for a single shard.

I would like to know what is the preferred way of taking backups in mongodb cluster. I have explored two options:

1. Approximate point in time consistent backup by taking the EBS snapshots around the same time. Advantage being, no write lock needs to be taken.
2. Stop writes on the system, then take snapshots. This would give point in time consistent backup.

Now, I'd like to know how is it actually done in production. I've read about replica set's secondary node being used, but not clear how it gives point in time consistent backup. Unless all the secondary nodes have a consistent point in time data, the EBS snapshot cannot be point in time. For example, what if for a secondary for NodeA, data is synced with primary, but some data for secondary for NodeB is not. Am I missing something here?

Also, can if ever happen that approach 1 leads to inconsistent MongoDB cluster (when restored), such that is crashes or stuff?

Comment: What is your setup? One replica set only or do you have a sharded cluster (multiple replica sets, config servers)? The backup for each of them is different. In general, if you can stop writes and you create an atomic snapshot for the primary, this is the easiest solution. You need to consider a lot of things (write concern, replication lag, oplog/journaling) to minimize data loss when servers crash.

Comment: No replica for now. Multiple shards and 3 config servers. Let me know if thats enough information for you to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Consistent backups

The first steps in any sharded cluster backup procedure should be to:

- Stop the balancer (including waiting for any migrations in progress to complete). Usually this is done with the  [`sh.stopBalancer()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-sharded-cluster-balancer/#disable-the-balancer) shell helper.
- Backup a config server (usually with the same method as your shard servers, so EBS or filesystem snapshot)

I would define a consistent backup of a sharded cluster as one where the sharded cluster metadata (i.e. the data stored on your config servers) corresponds with the backups for the individual shards, and each of the individual shards has been correctly backed up. Stopping the balancer ensures that no data migrations happen while your backup is underway.

Assuming your MongoDB data and journal files are on a single volume, you can take a consistent [EBS snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/) or [filesystem snapshot](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/backup-with-filesystem-snapshots/) without stopping writes to the node you are backing up. Snapshots occur asynchronously. Once an initial snapshot has been created, successive snapshots are incremental (only needing to update blocks that have changed since the previous snapshot).

#### Point-in-time backup

With an active sharded cluster, you can only easily capture a true point-in-time backup of data that has been written by stopping all writes to the cluster and backing up the primaries for each shard. Otherwise, as you have surmised, there may be differing replication lag between shards if you backup from secondaries. It's more common to backup from secondaries as there is some I/O overhead while the snapshots are written.

If you aren't using replication for your shards (or prefer to backup from primaries) the replication lag caveat doesn't apply, but the timing will be still be approximate for an active system as the snapshots need to be started simultaneously across all shards.

#### Point-in-time restore

Assuming all of your shards are backed by replica sets it is possible to use an approximate point-in-time consistent backup to orchestrate a *restore* to a more specific point-in-time using the [replica set oplog](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/replica-set-oplog/) for each of the shards (plus a config server). This is essentially the approach taken by backup solutions such as MongoDB Cloud Manager (née MMS): see [MongoDB Backup for Sharded Cluster](http://blog.mms.mongodb.com/post/83410779867/mongodb-backup-for-sharded-clusters). MongoDB Cloud Manager leverages backup agents on each shard for continuous backup using the replication oplog, and periodically creates full snapshots on a schedule. Point-in-time restores can be built by starting from a full data snapshot and then replaying the relevant oplogs up to a requested point-in-time.

#### What's the common production approach?

Downtime is generally not a desirable backup strategy for a production system, so the common approach is to take a consistent backup of a running sharded cluster at an approximate point-in-time using snapshots. Coordinating backup across a sharded cluster can be challenging, so backup tools/services are also worth considering. Backup services can also be more suitable if your deployment doesn't allow snapshots (for example, if your data and/or journal directories are spread across multiple volumes to maximise available IOPS).

Note: you should really, really consider using replication for your production deployment unless this is a non-essential cluster or downtime is acceptable. Replica sets help maximise uptime & availability for your deployment and some maintenance tasks (including backup) will be much more impactful without data redundancy.

Comment: Can you let me know how replica set can be used to ensure point in time consistent backup? I think unless we stop writes on the sharded cluster, we can never ensure that, can we? Also, how can we orchestrate a restore to a specific point in time using replica set oplog?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could share some links for orchestration of restore to specific point in time using replica set oplog

Comment: can you elaborate how replica sets help improve maintainance task like backup? Especially in context of getting point in time backup without using mongobackup/restore?

Comment: I think I've covered the caveats of point-in-time. If you want an absolute point-in-time backup you have to stop the world, but that generally isn't the desired approach for a sharded cluster in production. As long as you have taken a consistent backup, approximate point-in-time usually suffices for both backup & restore. If you need to restore to a more specific point-in-time you can dump & replay the replication oplogs (eg: [Modify and replay MongoDB oplog](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog)) from a newer snapshot to against an older snapshot.

Comment: Replica sets enable high availability, automatic failover, and rolling upgrades. Snapshots can degrade I/O performance (particularly the initial snapshot rather than subsquental incrementals) so taking backups on a secondary minimises potential overhead for your primary. The impact of snapshots may not be noticable if your deployment has ample available resource or the snapshots don't have a large delta to capture. Rolling upgrades on a replica set are where you upgrade each of the secondaries (eg. version upgrade) before finally stepping down and upgrading the former primary.

Comment: Without replica sets backing your shards you are vulnerable to a single node failure affecting your overall cluster availability (especially if you are using hashed shard keys or a shard key that requires scatter/gather queries). It's possible (though generally not useful except in desperation) to do [partial reads](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.addOption/#DBQuery.Option.partial) from a sharded cluster if one or more shards is unavailable, but you will be unable to insert/update any data on shards that are down.

Answer (score 0):

Your backup will be divided into multiple phases:

1. Stop the balancer on the `mongos` with `sh.stopBalancer()`
2. You can backup now the `config` database of the config servers. Does not matter whether you do it using EBS snapshots or `mongodump --oplog`
3. Now the shards and you can decide which way:

   1. Either: You backup every node with `mongodump --oplog`. You do not need to stop writes since you're snapshotting the oplog together with the database export. This backup allows a consistent restore. When restoring, you can use the `--oplogReplay` and the `--oplogLimit` options to specify a timestamp (assuming your oplog is sized appropriately and did not roll over during backup). You can perform a dump on all shards in parallel and by the restore is synchronized by the oplog.
   2. Or you fsync and lock and create an EBS snapshot (described http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/backup-and-restore-mongodb-on-amazon-ec2/) for every shard. MongoDB 3.0 cannot guarantee when using WiredTiger that the data files do not change. The cost here is, that you're required to stop all reads and writes since you have to unmount the device.
4. Now start the balancer on the `mongos` with `sh.startBalancer()`

Since you do not use replica sets, you have no hassle with lagging secondaries/a write is not replicated throughout the cluster. My favorite option is using `mongodump`/`mongorestore` which give a lot of control over the restore.

**Update:**

In the end, you've to decide, what you want to pay to get certain benefits:

1. Snapshots: Pay with space, write lock and a certain level of consistency to get fast backups, fast restore times and, not impacting performance after backup
2. Dumping: Pay with time and ousting the working set during backup to get smaller backups for consistent and slower restores, no write locks

Comment: But mongodump/restore is super slow for extremely large DBs. I envision my data size to grow beyong 500 GB. Is this a scalable solution?

Comment: I currently work with a database that is spread across 8 machines and has a size of 24TB and I'm not (yet) running into issues.

Comment: Running `mongodump` against a live server requires the data to be loaded in memory in order to dump it. This will affect your working set in memory and is particularly problematic if your overall data is much larger than memory or you have slow I/O. For that reason, most large production deployments typically use snapshots for minimal impact when backing up a live system.  `mongodump` output only includes data and the definitions of indexes (rather than the fully built data files & indexes), so the restoration time is usually significantly longer than restoring a snapshot.

Comment: @Stennie, that's exactly what I though regarding mongodump. They are slow and when you have disaster in case, it may take you several days with the kind of 24 TB data that you're talking about. That's why I was exploring the non - mongodump option. Let me know which of the two approaches I've mentioned make sense, or if you have a better snapshotting mechanism.

Comment: @mp911de Dont you think this thing would be ridiculously slow for disaster recovery? I'm pretty sure even taking the backup it self must take crazy amount of time

Comment: On replica sets, hardware failures are not a disaster, but when someone deletes data. The backup is started on the machines itself and then copied to the backup device. See, if you run into a disaster, that some data is gone and in the meantime, new data is written, snapshotting is not an option, because the snapshot would kill the newly written data. This again depends on your scenario. Since you have no replica sets, a disaster is when one shard dies. At this time, there is no data written to the shard so the snapshot has some advantages compared to `mongodump`