# How can I remove document from mongodb oplog collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-oplog

I have around 7 million document in oplog.$main in which 5 million of them are empty with no object like "o" : { }

I want to get rid of them to free up space, but not able to remove them. Any help is appreciated.

> db.oplog.$main.findOne()

{ "ts" : Timestamp(1443109104, 1), "op" : "n", "ns" : "", "o" : { } }

> db.oplog.$main.count({ "ts" : Timestamp(1443109104, 1)})

1

> db.oplog.$main.remove({ "ts" : Timestamp(1443109104, 1)})

WriteResult({ "writeError" : { "code" : 2, "errmsg" : "invalid collection name" } })

Comment: I'm not sure if you can manipulate oplog direclty.

Comment: maybe some useful infor could be found in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog?

Comment: @Saleem you are right, I cannot even insert record in 
oplog.> db.oplog.$main.insert({"data":"inserted"})

WriteResult({ "writeError" : { "code" : 2, "errmsg" : "invalid collection name" } })

Comment: See @zangw posted up in comments. It may help you.