# MongoDB stack trace in replica set due to DuplicateKey: E11000

Tags: mongodb, stack-trace, sharding

I have a mongodb cluster that holds our `development` and `production` databases.  Apparently last night while data was processing, one of the shard replica set servers had its mongod service throw an error.  Upon restarting the service, I repeatedly get errors related to batch operations failing due to `DuplicateKey: E11000` errors.

The backstory:

I have built an ETL engine that imports data from multiple sources, and stores them in a graph database implementation using mongodb.  The integrators translate the data to known nodes and saves them using bulk operations.
I also sometimes notice something is off with some of the rules for the node.  Thus I have to run a tool to massage the data after it exists in the database.

I was running those two operations on both `development` and `production`.

The mongodb cluster is fairly simple right now.  Two query servers talking to 1 config server (4 VM replica set) talking to 1 shard server (4 VM replica set).

When I am restarting the one `mongod` service, the service comes back up and pretty soon after throws another stack trace.

What I really need is just for the one VM to stop throwing a stack trace, and move on even though apparently the backed up operations are failing.

Is it possible to tell the replica set server to halt its queued operations in the op log?

```
2019-03-02T08:37:47.373-0500 F REPL     [repl writer worker 2] writer worker caught exception: DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: securityportal-development.core.nodes index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7a14795fe5e41db50036e3') } on: { op: "u", ns: "securityportal-development.core.nodes", ui: UUID("e2d48024-2c6d-4e46-a162-670959b8ae1e"), o: { $v: 1, $set: {...} }, ts: Timestamp(1551505421, 10), t: 8, h: -4266186036746248747, v: 2, wall: new Date(1551505421050) }
2019-03-02T08:37:47.472-0500 F REPL     [repl writer worker 14] writer worker caught exception: DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: securityportal-development.core.nodes index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7a147a5fe5e41db50036f3') } on: { op: "u", ns: "securityportal-development.core.nodes", ui: UUID("e2d48024-2c6d-4e46-a162-670959b8ae1e"), o: { $v: 1, $set: {... }, o2: { _id: ObjectId('5c7a147a5fe5e41db50036f3') }, ts: Timestamp(1551505421, 78), t: 8, h: -6279039002132381396, v: 2, wall: new Date(1551505421585) }
2019-03-02T08:37:47.796-0500 F REPL     [initandlisten] Failed to apply batch of operations. Number of operations in batch: 3422. First operation: { op: "u", ns: "config.system.sessions", ui: UUID("31fff722-6a5c-4947-b6f0-a83a98ef5a32"), o: { $v: 1, $set: { lastUse: new Date(1551505383010) } }, o2: { _id: { id: UUID("459b61e6-6744-41d8-a3ff-c2dfa3d8b71e"), uid: BinData(0, 56C1974FE3C40DBCDBFF60F66420E9AA79BA0B37F1138022B88B41E9BDF29678) } }, ts: Timestamp(1551505383, 24), t: 8, h: -8280419510924350842, v: 2, wall: new Date(1551505383004) }. Last operation: { op: "u", ns: "securityportal-development.core.nodes", ui: UUID("e2d48024-2c6d-4e46-a162-670959b8ae1e"), o: { $v: 1, $set: { ... }, o2: { _id: ObjectId('5c66c9dafa24cd52d2276e6d') }, ts: Timestamp(1551505423, 13), t: 8, h: 2759588341675508350, v: 2, wall: new Date(1551505423101) }. Oplog application failed in writer thread 1: DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: securityportal-development.core.nodes index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7a14795fe5e41db50036ca') }
2019-03-02T08:37:47.801-0500 F REPL     [initandlisten] Caught exception during replication recovery: DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: securityportal-development.core.nodes index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7a14795fe5e41db50036ca') }
2019-03-02T08:37:47.801-0500 F -        [initandlisten] terminate() called. An exception is active; attempting to gather more information
2019-03-02T08:37:47.811-0500 F -        [initandlisten] DBException::toString(): DuplicateKey: E11000 duplicate key error collection: securityportal-development.core.nodes index: _id_ dup key: { : ObjectId('5c7a14795fe5e41db50036ca') }
Actual exception type: mongo::error_details::ExceptionForImpl<(mongo::ErrorCodes::Error)11000, mongo::AssertionException>
 0x563bd0976761 0x563bd0976145 0x563bd0a6ac66 0x563bd0a6acb1 0x563bcf279e3f 0x563bcf2b401c 0x563bcf2b48e7 0x563bcef15ef8 0x563bceffd76b 0x563bcef92bc9 0x7f129f0b7b97 0x563bceffb8da
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"23FC761","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"23FC145"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"24F0C66","s":"_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"24F0CB1"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"CFFE3F","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl23ReplicationRecoveryImpl16recoverFromOplogEPNS_16OperationContextEN5boost8optionalINS_9TimestampEEE"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"D3A01C","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl21_startLoadLocalConfigEPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"D3A8E7","s":"_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl7startupEPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"99BEF8"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"A8376B","s":"_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"A18BC9","s":"main"},{"b":"7F129F096000","o":"21B97","s":"__libc_start_main"},{"b":"563BCE57A000","o":"A818DA","s":"_start"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "4.0.6", "gitVersion" : "caa42a1f75a56c7643d0b68d3880444375ec42e3", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.15.0-45-generic", "version" : "#48-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jan 29 16:28:13 UTC 2019", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "b" : "563BCE57A000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6C174EAF077366438A078C99465007456D76C8E4" }, { "b" : "7FFF29307000", "path" : "linux-vdso.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "025AD7BDF9DF8C7251192246537C451A988B98AE" }, { "b" : "7F12A0965000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CFC1F864E5F85EDA8E37B3BB238EC438D6D524A5" }, { "b" : "7F12A074A000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "390E9CC4C215314B6D8ADE6D6E28F8518418039C" }, { "b" : "7F12A02D2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A409BCD92DCDD3298E92C359876AC800FDD499AC" }, { "b" : "7F12A0068000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9787FF1FFFE8D82268D89F6BFA3AF07B3E9D140F" }, { "b" : "7F129FE64000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "25AD56E902E23B490A9CCDB08A9744D89CB95BCC" }, { "b" : "7F129FC5C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9826FBDF57ED7D6965131074CB3C08B1009C1CD8" }, { "b" : "7F129F8BE000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A33761AB8FB485311B3C85BF4253099D7CABE653" }, { "b" : "7F129F6A6000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "92E0BE1929D28508CF9C6D5754C7EB48C12255B3" }, { "b" : "7F129F487000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "28C6AADE70B2D40D1F0F3D0A1A0CAD1AB816448F" }, { "b" : "7F129F096000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B417C0BA7CC5CF06D1D1BED6652CEDB9253C60D0" }, { "b" : "7F12A0BE4000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "64DF1B961228382FE18684249ED800AB1DCEAAD4" }, { "b" : "7F129EE71000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnghttp2.so.14", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4F00E5207693FDC249DA42EC6472ACA6A7B929AE" }, { "b" : "7F129EC54000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "BA5BF9A5C44F48C647E9D8270A5421AE81CCAD61" }, { "b" : "7F129EA38000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librtmp.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69465D8AA6B19086ABF2455A703F9168BF82A69F" }, { "b" : "7F129E82A000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpsl.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CDAF1F1946846941F9D06414EC8C812D131A168E" }, { "b" : "7F129E5DF000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "00F419F64B0E70D8C5EEF7050369AA40B2A6E090" }, { "b" : "7F129E38D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9AFD2677E6CD2A67823EA74FDD8448F683028484" }, { "b" : "7F129E17F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "445EBBF9B2F0FC928017DF247244256F56D431E1" }, { "b" : "7F129DF62000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "EF3E006DFE3132A41D4D4DC0E407D6EA658E11C4" }, { "b" : "7F129DBE4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "62A44D226F3A74CF720305A52D3E876E214C248A" }, { "b" : "7F129D87F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.30", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F67AAC89381F6ACFE9979B24D4002668C4F70ABE" }, { "b" : "7F129D64B000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhogweed.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "842BDF0B0EAAB82E19F1EABFC38769F4040FBE31" }, { "b" : "7F129D415000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnettle.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C20D4B3BA13FCDCC3BF6857689BA9FC70BE3F6A5" }, { "b" : "7F129D194000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D40EA9B5EC5BC46799E4A412319617BD38BE9341" }, { "b" : "7F129CEBE000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69FBCF425EE6DF03DE93B82FBC2FC33790E68A96" }, { "b" : "7F129CC8C000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libk5crypto.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F400D5D643A7F9696DF0E6148FA99BEE6C1BDDF7" }, { "b" : "7F129CA88000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C0CB7E35A4566A443F99DFBC1A54D3A0677C8A10" }, { "b" : "7F129C87D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5support.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "D78D71E8E016A534281B25B97CD7E5E9DB5FE00A" }, { "b" : "7F129C662000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsasl2.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "ABB7E3F40302E6509DAD1F91DFB1F04B6A5FD072" }, { "b" : "7F129C421000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "A1A98DB481968073636BBAECB561A3EA8ED198AE" }, { "b" : "7F129C0F2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8DBD451EA5651283905E16FA7DFA9908688893A3" }, { "b" : "7F129BEDF000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6036B89A3BB671B32E01464C0C82BFA016186352" }, { "b" : "7F129BCDB000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkeyutils.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "F463E107B099910463BC32E837C73D341A52C27B" }, { "b" : "7F129BAD2000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "C2376C5B831991591F1A67B976758185F86896D8" }, { "b" : "7F129B845000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "69BDEE5FA0FEEDF317308BE850F78761861D520A" }, { "b" : "7F129B5A3000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "315D74995AAA32DE4D15BA25F335066988B1B230" }, { "b" : "7F129B36D000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "6673972A1C24A89EBAFBAE696188A4CB26C6DDEB" }, { "b" : "7F129B157000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "430827C33259C12248CF44B91A9A9821114376F5" }, { "b" : "7F129AF4F000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "3555B5F599C9787DFDDBF9E8DF6F706B9044D985" }, { "b" : "7F129AD26000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "93A0931B1C2818F0EA224CE6FE5E31E84A9B55BB" }, { "b" : "7F129AB17000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimbase.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "669D4CCE42FA4382796EFFCF0C16F459F4382C4C" }, { "b" : "7F129A8CD000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "4B80C543356EE0AF9039EFE7C9EA1CC1F74C426A" }, { "b" : "7F129A5C4000", "path" : "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "9FD7B69263297314C83BB205234E182BD4D8B86A" }, { "b" : "7F129A38C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "810686AF0D5FD350A4FB1CC4B5AFF44A05C102CB" } ] }}
 mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x41) [0x563bd0976761]
 mongod(+0x23FC145) [0x563bd0976145]
 mongod(_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+0x6) [0x563bd0a6ac66]
 mongod(+0x24F0CB1) [0x563bd0a6acb1]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl23ReplicationRecoveryImpl16recoverFromOplogEPNS_16OperationContextEN5boost8optionalINS_9TimestampEEE+0xC7F) [0x563bcf279e3f]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl21_startLoadLocalConfigEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x54C) [0x563bcf2b401c]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo4repl26ReplicationCoordinatorImpl7startupEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x237) [0x563bcf2b48e7]
 mongod(+0x99BEF8) [0x563bcef15ef8]
 mongod(_ZN5mongo11mongoDbMainEiPPcS1_+0x10DB) [0x563bceffd76b]
 mongod(main+0x9) [0x563bcef92bc9]
 libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xE7) [0x7f129f0b7b97]
 mongod(_start+0x2A) [0x563bceffb8da]
-----  END BACKTRACE  -----
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modify and replay MongoDB oplog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444920/modify-and-replay-mongodb-oplog)

Comment: I like the concept of implementing a data backup strategy.  I can potentially use some of the tips in the referred question for my situation.  But I did not see that error in my primary log. I would have expected to see this write error in the pm2 logs, but I don't.  I also do not see that error in any of the other 3 replica set member VMs.  This tells me there is something off about the 4th member, which is the one that keeps crashing.  My assumption now is that the other 3 members have good data, and somehow the 4th is now bad.